# mock third party method +jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am using jest for my backend unit testing.I need to mock third party library  module methods using that.I tried the following code:

My controller file:

```
    const edgejs = require('apigee-edge-js');
    const apigeeEdge = edgejs.edge;
   async get(req, res) {
    const abc= await apigeeEdge.connect(connectOptions);
    const Details = await abc.developers.get(options);
    return res.status(200).send(Details);
  }
```

test.spec.js

```
    let edgejs = require('apigee-edge-js');
    const ctrl = require('../../controller');
    describe("Test suite for abc", () => {
        test("should return ...", async() =>{        
            edgejs.edge = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(async () => 
            {return  {"connect":{"developers":{"get":[{}]}}}}
           );
         ctrl.get(req, res)    
    });
```

But its not mocking , its calling the actual library connect method. What i am doing wrong here. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

**WORKING CODE**

```
jest.mock('apigee-edge-js', () => {
    return { edge: { connect: jest.fn() } };
  });

    const edgejs = require('apigee-edge-js');
    test("should return ...", async () => {
        edgejs.edge.connect.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(
            {"developers":{"get":[{}]}}
          ));    
        edgejs.edge.connect()
        expect(edgejs.edge.connect).toBeCalled();
        
      })
```

**ERROR CODE:**

```
jest.mock('apigee-edge-js', () => {
    return { edge: { connect: jest.fn() } };
  });

const Ctrl = require('../../controllers/controller'); ----> Extra line
const edgejs = require('apigee-edge-js');

test("should return ...", async () => {
    edgejs.edge.connect.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(
        {"developers":{"get":[{}]}}
      ));
    const req = mockRequest();
     const res = mockResponse();
    await Ctrl.get(req, res)  ---> Extra line
    expect(edgejs.edge.connect).toBeCalled();       
    
  });
```

Receceivig erro : TypeError: edgejs.edge.connect.mockImplementationOnce is not a function

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unknown at which point the method is called. edgejs.edge is not a function and shouldn't be mocked as a function (and you should never mock methods with `= jest.fn()` because they cannot be restored). Mocking the entire module likely makes more sense.

Comment: @ Estus Flask I cant provide the whole code base because of some security reasons. I am ready to give details if needed . Can you help me on this?? `Mocking the entire module likely makes more sense` how can i acheive this??

Comment: Please, see what MCVE is. It's totally unnecessary to provide the whole code. If you can fully reproduce the problem in 10 lines, make it 10 lines. As for modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks

Comment: @Estus Flask Edited the post . Can you see whether it will be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mock doesn't affect anything because `controller` dereferences `edgejs.edge` right after it's imported, `apigeeEdge = edgejs.edge`. This would be different if it were using `edgejs.edge.connect` instead of `apigeeEdge.connect`.

Methods shouldn't be mocked as `... = jest.fn()` because this prevents them from being restored and may affect other tests after that; this is what `jest.spyOn` is for. Furthermore, `edge` is an object and not a method.

Jest provides module mocking functionality. Third-party libraries generally need to be mocked in unit tests.

It should be:

```
jest.mock('apigee-edge-js', () => {
  return { edge: { connect: jest.fn() } };
});

const ctrl = require('../../controller');
const edgejs = require('apigee-edge-js');

test("should return ...", async () => {
  edgejs.edge.connect.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(
    {"developers":{"get":[{}]}}
  ));
  await ctrl.get(req, res)
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still i am not clear , what should be there `mockImplementationOnce(...)` ?? The above code is test file alone??? Also first we should mock ans then require?? Can you please be elaborate i am very new to this.

Comment: I've updated it. Mock goes before require. Most times `jest.mock` is hoisted above imports even if you write it below, but this depends on your setup and requires Jest to be correctly configured, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#using-with-es-module-imports .

Comment: receiving error    `TypeError: edgejs.edge.connect.mockImplementationOnce is not a function`

Comment: It's expected to be workable, considering that `jest.mock` part was done correctly. Double check it. See https://repl.it/repls/CheeryCyanCad#sum.test.js

Comment: The same code is not working for me. receving the above error. i am using node -v `10.14.1` and `jest@^25.2.2` some version issue??

Comment: The issue is If i require controller then i am getting the error. Without controller import its working fine. Any idea whats happening?? Whether controller's apigee-edge-js is overriding mocked one??

Comment: It could be the case if `jest.mock` weren't the first line in the test. But if it is the first one, this leaves no place for error, controller module should get a mocked module, too.

Comment: I am pretty sure, mock is the first line in my file, still i am getting the above error

Comment: @Subburaj I'm unaware of any condition under which this may happen for the specified test. Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Edited  my post.Please have a look.

Comment: Finally i got it worked. The trick is controller should be required after mock Implemenatation. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Do you mean that mockImplementationOnce should go before `const ctrl = ...`? I have no good explanation for that.

Comment: Yes After mockImpplemenationOnce we should require the controller. I also dont have any proper explanation for this. i just saw this some other post and tried for this. Plz let me know if you got any idea about hits.